# Custom theme covering up admin toolbar.

Tags: theming, toolbar

I am trying to convert a template to a custom drupal 8 theme and am having trouble with it covering the admin toolbar when logged in. I tried to inspect bootstrap when installed to see what was added but to no avail.  I am trying to create a custom theme from scratch and not a subtheme.  Any help is appreciated to find out what css that I can add that will push the content down while logged in?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Drupal 8 admin toolbar z-index value is 502 only, but the bootstrap default static navbar z-index value is 1000, I think, Increase the admin toolbar z-index value would fix the issue,

```
.toolbar-oriented .toolbar-bar {
 z-index: 1001 /* or more */
}
```

Place that code in your theme's custom css file :)

Comment: i just figured it out.  my body on my custom theme has no classes added to it when i log in, but when i change to bartik or bootstrap there are classes plus a padding-top that appears to be calculated from the toolbar height (79px).  I need help figuring out how to add that when I switch to my custom theme.

Comment: Just copy html.html.twig file from classy theme and paste it in your custom theme folder.. Then you could add class directly in the body  tag in the file